# Posts picking up old Permalinks, how to reset?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I've come across a small bug with my yoast breadcrumbs.

I've rebuilding a site and have imported some old posts and content and have come across a problem where yoast things the permalinks are still the old ones. I've flushed out all the old categories and tags, etc and have used flush_rewrite_rules() to try and fix it which has resulted in some broken links.

Am I missing something in the DB?

Comment: Seems it was a bug with yoast possibly. Switching over the NavXT seems to have given me the control to fix it.

Comment: Great that you found the solution yourself. If you can write it in an answer (you can do this for your own question too) and mark it as "accepted", this question will no longer be in the "unanswered" state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the Yoast Plugin, which was fixed by switching on to the NavXT Plugin to do breadcrumbs instead.